# Create a Windows 64-Bit executable with YASM assembler

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, nasm, yasm

I would like to create a Windows 10/11 Pro 64-Bit assembly source code, that can than proceed by YASM Assembler to form a Windows Executable (.exe Application) so small as possible.
For Resources under the GitHub: [corkami](https://github.com/corkami/pocs/tree/master/PE).

But I don't know which one is best for 64-bit. The solution should contain Assembly text/code with comments that explain how to do so.

E.g.: "You have to set the IAT for more as one Symbols" ...
The solution should be "not" link with other Tool-chains. This means: `C:\yasm -f bin -o output.exe input.asm`.

As a bonus, the source should be compile with `C:\nasm -f bin -o output.exe input.asm`.

In an answer, it is enough to show the way/steps, to display a *MessageBox*, and *ExitProcess *call.

Optional, __imp__ShowMessageBoxA is an Export-Symbol from the FPC (Free-Pascal-Compiler) Windows .DLL library file. The assembly should contain this snippet:

```
EntryPoint:
    sub rsp, 4 * 8
    mov ecx, 0                     // HWND
    mov rdx, [lpText]              // LPCTSTR
    mov r8, [lpCapt]               // LPCTSTR
    mov r9d, 2                     // UINT
    call [__imp__ShowMessageBoxA]

    xor ecx, ecx
    call [__imp__ExitProcess]

lpText db "this and that", 0
lpCapt db "Caption", 0

hnExitProcess:
    dw 0
    db 'ExitProcess', 0
hnShowMessageBoxA:
    dw 0
    db 'ShowMessageBoxA', 0
```

I tried to use a Example from  [corkami](https://github.com/corkami/pocs/tree/master/PE), but I am lost.

I tried to create flat binary File with **yasm.exe -f bin**  or  **nasm.exe -f bin**  which does bring me no Compiler-Errors.
The result of yasm -f bin output.exe was the Windows Loader Message: "Symbol ShowMessageBoxA was not found in output.exe". I created a .DLL that was formed by FPC (Free Pascal Compiler) with **C:\fpc kalle32.pas** :

```
library kalle32;
uses Windows;
procedure ShowMessageA(h: HWND; t,c: LPCTSTR; u: UINT); stdcall;       export;
begin
  // this will not show
  MessageBoxA(h,t,c,u);
end;
begin
  // this message box will not display on start up on DLL load
  MessageBoxA(0,'Test Message','Caption',0);
end.
```

I would like to write assembly Code that can compiled with **yasm.exe** or **nasm.exe** under the Command Line/Console/Terminal to an executable.

---

@Margaret Bloom: the smallest/full reproduce example is this one:

```
BITS 64

%define align(n,r) (((n+(r-1))/r)*r)

; DOS Header
    dw 'MZ'                 ; e_magic
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_cblp
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] c_cp
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_crlc
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_cparhdr
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_minalloc
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_maxalloc
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_ss
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_sp
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_csum
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_ip
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_cs
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_lfarlc
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_ovno
    times 4 dw 0            ; [UNUSED] e_res
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_oemid
    dw 0                    ; [UNUSED] e_oeminfo
    times 10 dw 0           ; [UNUSED] e_res2
    dd pe_hdr               ; e_lfanew

; PE Header
pe_hdr:
    dw 'PE', 0              ; Signature

; Image File Header
    dw 0x8664               ; Machine
    dw 0x01                 ; NumberOfSections
    dd 0                    ; [UNUSED] TimeDateStamp
    dd 0                    ; PointerToSymbolTable
    dd 0                    ; NumberOfSymbols
    dw opt_hdr_size         ; SizeOfOptionalHeader
    dw 0x22                 ; Characteristics

; Optional Header, COFF Standard Fields
opt_hdr:
    dw 0x020b               ; Magic (PE32+)
    db 0x0e                 ; MajorLinkerVersion
    db 0x16                 ; MinorLinkerVersion
    dd code_size            ; SizeOfCode
    dd 0                    ; SizeOfInitializedData
    dd 0                    ; SizeOfUninitializedData
    dd entry                ; AddressOfEntryPoint
    dd iatbl                ; BaseOfCode

; Optional Header, NT Additional Fields
    dq 0x000140000000       ; ImageBase
    dd 0x10                 ; SectionAlignment
    dd 0x10                 ; FileAlignment
    dw 0x06                 ; MajorOperatingSystemVersion
    dw 0                    ; MinorOperatingSystemVersion
    dw 0                    ; MajorImageVersion
    dw 0                    ; MinorImageVersion
    dw 0x06                 ; MajorSubsystemVersion
    dw 0                    ; MinorSubsystemVersion
    dd 0                    ; Reserved1
    dd file_size            ; SizeOfImage
    dd hdr_size             ; SizeOfHeaders
    dd 0                    ; CheckSum
    dw 0x02                 ; Subsystem (Windows GUI)
    dw 0x8160               ; DllCharacteristics
    dq 0x100000             ; SizeOfStackReserve
    dq 0x1000               ; SizeOfStackCommit
    dq 0x100000             ; SizeOfHeapReserve
    dq 0x1000               ; SizeOfHeapCommit
    dd 0                    ; LoaderFlags
    dd 0x02                 ; NumberOfRvaAndSizes

; Optional Header, Data Directories
    dd 0                    ; Export, RVA
    dd 0                    ; Export, Size
    dd itbl                 ; Import, RVA
    dd itbl_size            ; Import, Size

opt_hdr_size equ $-opt_hdr

; Section Table
    section_name db '.'     ; Name
    times 8-($-section_name) db 0
    dd sect_size            ; VirtualSize
    dd iatbl                ; VirtualAddress
    dd code_size            ; SizeOfRawData
    dd iatbl                ; PointerToRawData
    dd 0                    ; PointerToRelocations
    dd 0                    ; PointerToLinenumbers
    dw 0                    ; NumberOfRelocations
    dw 0                    ; NumberOfLinenumbers
    dd 0x60000020           ; Characteristics

hdr_size equ $-$$

code:
; Import Address Directory
iatbl:
    dq symbol
    dq 0

iatbl_size equ $-iatbl

; Strings
title:
    db "Hallo Welt !!!", 0
content:
    db "ABCDEFGHIJKL", 0

; Entry
entry:
; the comment block there are my interest in - why does it not work
    mov r9d, 0x00240040     ; uType
    lea r8, [rel title]     ; lpCaption
    lea rdx, [rel content]  ; lpText
    xor ecx, ecx            ; hWnd
    jmp [rel iatbl]         ; MessageBoxN

    times align($-$$,16)-($-$$) db 0xcc

; Import Directory
itbl:
    dq intbl                ; OriginalFirstThunk
    dd 0                    ; TimeDateStamp
    dd dll_name             ; ForwarderChain
    dd iatbl                ; Name
    dq 0                    ; FirstThunk

itbl_size equ $-itbl

; Import Name Table
intbl:
    dq symbol
    dq 0

; Symbol
symbol:
    dw 0x0294               ; [UNUSED] Function Order
    db 'MessageBoxA', 0     ; Function Name
dll_name:
    db 'USER32.dll', 0
    db 0

sect_size equ $-code

    times align($-$$,16)-($-$$) db 0

code_size equ $-code
file_size equ $-$$
```

I would extend the Assembly Script above so, that I can use more than one win32api Functions. So, I would use a second, third, ... Function from my own .DLL Files on ground of the existing Code above.

Comment: `__imp_` is correct prefix. not `__imp__`. must be `__imp_ShowMessageBoxA`, `__imp_ExitProcess` etc

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are using a set of included files designed to replicate the PE file format with a set of macros that come no shy of insanity. If you want to follow that road, you need to make a [MCVE] because we can't tell what `__imp__ShowMessageBoxA` is (or why you wanted to replicate the MS linker naming convention for `__dllspec(dllimport)` names when you won't use a linker in the first place). For all we know you may have made the IAT entry wrong. If you want to create a very small PE, start by making a normal PE and then edit it with a PE viewer or hex editor. If you ...

Comment: ... need to be in the form of an assembly file, just turn the headers into a long array of bytes. It won't be more obscure than that framework that uses macros like `_d` and `_c` and has no pedagogical value.

Comment: @MargaretBloom  I have change the source code, so you can create a flat file on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do what I want. It can be compiled with NASM, and it (the resulting flat image executable .EXE) shows a Ansi-, and a Unicode Version of MessageBoxA/W described in the Microsoft documentation. This can be used to create a Flat Image on the fly with NASM assembly.

```
SECTIONS   equ 2
TIME_DATE   equ 0
IMAGE_BASE        equ    0x000140000000 ;0x400000 ; org
SECTION_ALIGNMENT   equ     0x200
FILE_ALIGNMENT    equ      0x200

BSS_SIZE equ 0

%define nagoa_round(size) ((size + SECTION_ALIGNMENT - 1) & ~(SECTION_ALIGNMENT - 1))

bits 64
org IMAGE_BASE

section .text

;;******************************************************************************************************
;; if the header is part of the image, define it as section .text because .text is put
;; first in the image, and rename the code section as section .code

header:

   dw "MZ"                   ; e_magic
   dw 0                       ; e_cblp
   dw 0                       ; e_cp
   dw 0                       ; e_crlc
   dw 0                       ; e_cparhdr
   dw 0                       ; e_minalloc
   dw 0                       ; e_maxalloc
   dw 0                       ; e_ss
   dw 0                       ; e_sp
   dw 0                       ; e_csum
   dw 0                       ; e_ip
   dw 0                       ; e_cs
   dw 0                       ; e_lsarlc
   dw 0                       ; e_ovno
   dq 0                       ; e_res
   dw 0                       ; e_oemid
   dw 0                       ; e_oeminfo
   dd 0,0,0,0,0                    ; e_res2
   dd imageHeader - IMAGE_BASE   ; e_lfanew

imageHeader:

   dd "PE"               ; Signature
   dw 0x8664              ; Machine
   dw SECTIONS           ; NumberOfSections
   dd TIME_DATE          ; TimeDateStamp
   dd 0                   ; PointerToSymbolTable
   dd 0                   ; NumberOfSymbols
   dw optionalHeader.SIZE   ; SizeOfOptionalHeader
   dw 0x022               ; Characteristics

optionalHeader:

    dw 0x20B                      ; Magic
    db 0                           ; MajorLinkerVersion
    db 0                           ; MinorLinkerVersion
    dd nagoa_round(RAW_CODE.SIZE)   ; SizeOfCode
    dd nagoa_round(RAW_DATA.SIZE)   ; SizeOfInitializedData
    dd nagoa_round(BSS_SIZE)      ; SizeOfUninitializedData
    dd entryPoint                 ; AddressOfEntryPoint
    dd code                        ; BaseOfCode
    ;dd data - IMAGE_BASE          ; BaseOfData
    dq IMAGE_BASE                 ; ImageBase
    dd SECTION_ALIGNMENT          ; SectionAlignment
    dd FILE_ALIGNMENT             ; FileAlignment
    dw 4                           ; MajorOperatingSystemVersion
    dw 0                           ; MinorOperatingSystemVersion
    dw 0                           ; MajorImageVersion
    dw 0                           ; MinorImageVersion
    dw 4                           ; MajorSubsystemVersion
    dw 0                           ; MinorSubsystemVersion
    dd 0                           ; Win32VersionValue
    dd (RAW_HEADER.SIZE + RAW_CODE.SIZE + RAW_DATA.SIZE); SizeOfImage

    dd RAW_HEADER.SIZE            ; SizeOfHeaders
    dd 0                           ; CheckSum
    dw 2                           ; Subsystem
    dw 0                           ; DllCharacteristics
    dq 0x40000                     ; SizeOfStackReserve
    dq 0x6000                      ; SizeOfStackCommit
    dq 0x100000                    ; SizeOfHeapReserve
    dq 0x1000                      ; SizeOfHeapCommit
    dd 0                           ; LoaderFlags
    dd 16                          ; NumberOfRvaAndSizes
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT
   dd Import_Directory_Table, Import_Directory_Table_Size                       ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DEBUG
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COPYRIGHT
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_GLOBALPTR
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_TLS
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT
   ;dd Import_Address_Table, Import_Address_Table_Size                       ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT
   dd 0,0
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT
   dd 0, 0                        ; IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR
   dd 0, 0                        ; reserved

optionalHeader.SIZE equ $ - optionalHeader

sectionHeaders:

    db ".text", 0, 0, 0            ; Name
    dd nagoa_round(RAW_CODE.SIZE)   ; VirtualSize
    dd code                       ; VirtualAddress
    dd RAW_CODE.SIZE              ; SizeOfRawData
    dd RAW_CODE.OFFSET            ; PointerToRawData
    dd 0                           ; PointerToRelocations
    dd 0                           ; PointerToLinenumbers
    dw 0                           ; NumberOfRelocations
    dw 0                           ; NumberOfLinenumbers
    dd 0x60000020                  ; Characteristics

    db ".data", 0, 0, 0            ; Name
    dd nagoa_round(RAW_DATA.SIZE)   ; VirtualSize
    dd data                       ; VirtualAddress
    dd RAW_DATA.SIZE              ; SizeOfRawData
    dd RAW_DATA.OFFSET            ; PointerToRawData
    dd 0                           ; PointerToRelocations
    dd 0                           ; PointerToLinenumbers
    dw 0                           ; NumberOfRelocations
    dw 0                           ; NumberOfLinenumbers
    dd 0xC0000040                  ; Characteristics

align FILE_ALIGNMENT, db 0
RAW_HEADER.SIZE equ $ - header

;;******************************************************************************************************
;;   F I R S T  . c o d e  S E C T I O N
;;******************************************************************************************************

VS_CODE   EQU ( ( ( 1 + ( (RAW_HEADER.SIZE-1) >> 12 ) ) * SECTION_ALIGNMENT ) )

section .code vstart=VS_CODE

   code:
   entryPoint:
      mov rcx,500
      call [rel Sleep]
      mov r9d, 0x00240040 ; uType
      lea r8, [rel title] ; lpCaption
      lea rdx, [rel content] ; lpText
      xor ecx, ecx ; hWnd
      call [rel MessageBoxA]
      mov rcx,500
      call [rel Sleep]
      mov r9d, 0x00240040 ; uType
      lea r8, [rel TITLE_W] ; lpCaption
      lea rdx, [rel CONTENT_W] ; lpText
      xor ecx, ecx ; hWnd
      call [rel MessageBoxW]
      jmp [rel ExitProcess]

   align SECTION_ALIGNMENT, db 0

;;******************************************************************************************************
;;   F I R S T  . d a t a  S E C T I O N
;;******************************************************************************************************

VS_DATA   EQU ( VS_CODE + ( ( 1 + ( (RAW_CODE.SIZE-1) >> 12 ) ) * SECTION_ALIGNMENT ) )

section .data vstart=VS_DATA
data :
    Import_Address_Table:
      DLL_1:
        Sleep:         dq I_Sleep
        ExitProcess:   dq I_ExitProcess
        GetStdHandle:  dq I_GetStdHandle
        dq              0
      DLL_2:
      MessageBoxA    dq I_MessageBoxA
      MessageBoxW    dq I_MessageBoxW
      dq              0
   Import_Address_Table_Size equ $ - Import_Address_Table
   
      align 0x20, db 0
        Import_Directory_Table:
            KERNEL32.originalfthk    dd DLL_1_thunk_table
            KERNEL32.timedate        dd 0 
            KERNEL32.forwarder       dd 0 
            KERNEL32.name            dd dll_name_1
            KERNEL32.firstthunk      dd DLL_1

            USER32.originalfthk    dd DLL_2_thunk_table
            USER32.timedate        dd 0 
            USER32.forwarder       dd 0 
            USER32.name            dd dll_name_2
            USER32.firstthunk      dd DLL_2
         
      align 0x20, db 0            ; should be always at the end of Import_Directory_Table
      
      Import_Directory_Table_Size equ $ - Import_Directory_Table

      DLL_1_thunk_table :
         dq I_Sleep
         dq   I_ExitProcess
         dq   I_GetStdHandle
         dq 0
      DLL_2_thunk_table :
         dq I_MessageBoxA
         dq   I_MessageBoxW
         dq 0
        I_Sleep:          
            dw               0
            db               'Sleep', 0 
            align            2 , db 0 
        I_ExitProcess:  
            dw               0 
            db               'ExitProcess', 0
            align            2 , db 0 
        I_GetStdHandle:
            dw               0 
            db               'GetStdHandle', 0
         align            2 , db 0 
        I_MessageBoxA:
            dw               0 
            db               'MessageBoxA', 0
         align            2 , db 0 
        I_MessageBoxW:
            dw               0 
            db               'MessageBoxW', 0
         align            2 , db 0 
        dll_name_1:            db 'kernel32.dll', 0
        dll_name_2:           db 'user32.dll', 0
   
    STRING_TABLE:
   %define u(x) __?utf16le?__(x)
   %define w(x) __?utf32le?__(x)
   title:
         db "Hello world !!!", 0
         align            2 , db 0 
   content:
         db "ABCDEFGHIJKL", 0
         align            2 , db 0    
   TITLE_W:         
         dw u("Hello World !!! in Unicode"),0
         align            2 , db 0 
   CONTENT_W:
         db u("ABCDEFGHIJKL"), 0
         align            2 , db 0 
   align SECTION_ALIGNMENT, db 0
;;******************************************************************************************************
;;   L A S T  . c o d e  S E C T I O N
;;******************************************************************************************************
section .code

align FILE_ALIGNMENT, db 0

RAW_CODE.OFFSET   equ RAW_HEADER.SIZE
RAW_CODE.SIZE   equ $ - $$

;;******************************************************************************************************
;;   L A S T  . d a t a  S E C T I O N
;;******************************************************************************************************
section .data

align FILE_ALIGNMENT, db 0

RAW_DATA.OFFSET   equ RAW_CODE.OFFSET + RAW_CODE.SIZE
RAW_DATA.SIZE   equ $ - $$

;;******************************************************************************************************

IMAGE_END equ $

;; -- eof --
```